# How to keep my app flutter always on top, having priority over the others?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I developed an application that uses **NFC** technology to receive some data when the badge is passed. 
When the app is open the screen must always remain accessible and this happens through the use of an external library. It works correctly, but if for example a popup is displayed warning you to update the device, **the device goes to lock** or if I pass the badge while this window is shown the device **instead of using my app to detect the nfc tag uses the system one** . How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can you share some snippet or link if so?

Comment: @Jas no, i think a solution could be to take the complete control ok the device, i saw somes guide lines but not for flutter

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're going to need to do for this is use a [background isolate](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes).